# Add .txt extension to user input form

Tags: html

I have some code to allow me to search for a "file.txt" to show the results inside an iframe, but instead of the user typing "example.txt" I need it to only have to type "example" and then add the .txt extension automatically. How can I do this with my current code:

```
<script>
            function append(){

                var text1=document.getElementById("input1").value;
                document.getElementById("iframe1").setAttribute("src",text1);
            }

            </script>
            </form> 
            <form name="inputForm" action="" method="get">
            <font size="5">File: </font><input type="text" id="input1" name="user">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="append()">
            </form> 
            <iframe id="iframe1" name="frame" src="(FILE).txt" frameborder="1" height="350" width="400" ></iframe>
```

This method works perfectly, but how can I achieve the same results without having to type .txt?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should work fine .appendTo();

```
http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append `.txt` to the string, no?

```
function append(){
    var text1=document.getElementById("input1").value;
    document.getElementById("iframe1").setAttribute("src", text1+".txt");
}
```

Comment: Wow, I thought it was that but I used text1+".txt" instead. How silly of me...

Thanks so much, you helped a newbie out!

Comment: @Jake Using single or double quotes doesn't matter :)